# Navigation Bar and Tab Bar in Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, navigation

Background:

I have an iOS app in the app store, but it's running on a very old version of Cordova that needs to be updated.  Unfortunately, the plugins I have been using for the [navigation bar](https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-ios-navigationbar-plugin) and for the [tab bar](https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-ios-tabbar-plugin) are not compatible with the current version of iOS.

There are HTML toolkits that include this type of functionality, but in my case, I can't use them.  I'm actually loading the web app from a web server rather than locally, and any communication errors would break HTML navigation. (I realize this is not ideal, but it is beyond my control.)

Question:

I have searched for other navigation bar and tab bar plugins, but I haven't found anything of interest.  It seems to me that I'm missing something.  Is there an easier way to add navigation controls to a Cordova app?  Is there a plugin that I haven't found?

Comment: I don't totally understand the nature of your problem. If you can use plugins (which are local, too) to implement those bars, why can't you just use plain HTML to do that? And if you can use plain HTML, you can use HTML frameworks that provide such functionality out-of-box.

Comment: @sanfor, A plugin can be initialized from the web and then run natively.  So once the tab and nav bars are initialized, they will continue to work even if a page times out (e.g. the user can hit the back button and try again.)  However, if I implemented the navigation in HTML, and the page timed out, the user would only have a blank screen to interact with.

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is for.  Would the voter care to leave a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately just fixed the AndiDog plugins to work on iOS8.

Comment: Any change you might make this fix public? You could submit a PR to AndiDog's plugin repos?

Comment: @AlexandreTestu That's a valid point.  Unfortunately, I extensively modified the plugins, due in part to my unusual constraints, so I probably ruined a lot of functionality that most people used.

Having said that, I mostly just had to fix ARC stuff, which was pretty simple.  And I updated the javascript to make the new exec() call.  But all of that wasn't as hard as I feared.

Comment: How do you navigate between tabs in andi dog plugin ?

Comment: I'm sorry to say I can't help much.  I became more dissatisfied with the plugins, so I completely rewrote them from scratch in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but I have created a tab-bar system created in JS/HTML for hybrid apps and web apps. (That runs locally!). It's called [app-tab-bar](https://erlendellingsen.github.io/app-tab-bar/).